# Object destructuring to update one field value of nested object

Tags: typescript

I have an custom type:

```
type Product = {
  info1: {
    name: string;
    id: number;
  };
  info2: {
    name: string;
    id: number;
  };
};
```

Then, I received a value with type `Product`.  I would like to update only the `id` of its `info2`, I try to use object destructuring to achieve it:

```
const receivedProd: Product = getProduct();
const updatedProduct = {...receivedProd, //but how to update only `id` of `info2` here?}
```

I get stuck on how can I elegantly update the value of `id` of `info2` field with above syntax?

Comment: I don't see how this has to do with `typescript-typings`; could you remove that tag?

Comment: Generally speaking when I hear "update" I think "mutation", so you'd just write `receivedProp.info2.id = 123`.  If you want a new object then you'll have to do some kind of deep copy (or at least deep in the `info2` property), so something like `const updatedProduct = { ...receivedProd, info2: { ...receivedProd.info2, id: 123 } };`.  I can imagine making that a function like `update(receivedProp, ["info2", "id"], 123)`, but it depends on what you mean by "elegantly".

Comment: Yes, I would like to have a new object, not direct update the received one. Thanks.

Comment: Consider the [immutable-js](https://immutable-js.com/) library for this kind of thing. It allows you to update nested records with syntax like `const updatedProduct = setIn(receivedProduct, ['info2', 'id'], 123);`.

Comment: And does it have to be completely new, or just the modified path is new?   That is, is it okay if `receivedProd.info1 === udatedProd.info1` because `info1` doesn't change?  Assuming so then you could maybe do [this](https://tsplay.dev/NnQ9vw) (which attempts to give `updateNestedProp()` typings that care about correct paths.